# How do I make pods installed with CocoaPods available to ALL projects in my workspace?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.6, cocoapods

I'm using `XCode 4.6.1`. I have several projects in my workspace, but only one of them is able to include libraries added with `CocoaPods`. The other projects don't detect them at all.

How do I share my `CocoaPods` with the entire workspace? Do I need to include `libPods.a` in the build dependencies of all projects? Do I need to add something special to the podfile?

Answer (score 8):

By default CocoaPods only links with the first target it finds. You probably want to look at the [xcodeproj](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#xcodeproj) and [link_with](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#link_with) Podfile directives.

Comment: if ever an answer deserved a check, this is it.